# 3-way Chi-Squared Test in R

Tags: r, testing, statistics

I have categorical data as follows:

```
gender age_group diagnosis
male     young    x
female   child    y
female   adult    x
male     old      z

gender, age_group and diagnosis have 2, 4 and 3 levels respectively.
```

I want to conduct a `Chi-Squared Test` to see the relationship between two categories. How could I do that in R

Comment: You need to do multiple pairwise chi-squared tests as far as I understand.

Comment: You mean I use chisq.test(gender, diagnosis), chisq.test(gender, age_group) and chisq.test(age_group, diagnosis) ?

Comment: You can carry out the Chi-Squared Test of Independence on a 3-way table. See https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat504/print/book/export/html/102. In particular, the section "Boy Scounts and Juvenile Delinquency". However, you need to explicitly calculate the expected counts to get the chi-sq statistic instead of relying on `chisq.test`. See the associated R-code: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat504/sites/onlinecourses.science.psu.edu.stat504/files/lesson05/boys.out

Answer (score 4):

The appropriate test for three dimensional contigency tables is the [Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%E2%80%93Mantel%E2%80%93Haenszel_statistics) I believe. In order to use it, you will need to convert your data into a three dimensional array, and make sure that each possible `stratum` in your resulting contigency table has a frequency > 1.

```
# convert data to contigency table
df <- table(data)

# run test
mantelhaen.test(df)
```

Comment: The CMH tests for conditional independence while the chi-sq test for mutual independence [see https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat504/book/export/html/102]